# Delete File With Unlink Resource Temp Unavailable

Tags: php, jscript, unlink

I Am trying to delete a file that is being replaced with a new file upload, However i am using unlink an i get the error RESOURCE TEMP UNAVAILABLE

tried to wait for a few seconds before trying to unlink.
tried unsetting the temp file

```
 if (isset($_POST['oldimagesrc'])){ $oldimagesrc=$_POST['oldimagesrc'];
 $oldimagesrc = filter_var($oldimagesrc, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $oldimagesrc = strip_tags($oldimagesrc);

 $dir="../imageupload/images/";

 $oldimagelocation = $dir.$oldimagesrc;

 $tempfile=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];


 if (move_uploaded_file($tempfile,$newimagelocation)) {

  if (unlink($oldimagelocation)) {                                                                                  

   die($savetoDB);

     exit();

 }

 else 

 {

  die("Could Not Delete File");

  exit();

}


 }
```

I would hope there is some work around like a way to clear the cached file allthough i have tried to unset the temp file..

P.S

Sometimes it works while other times i get the error...

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to rename the file after upload and save.
2. Store renamed file path or name into the database.
3. Get OLD Filename & store at local variable.
4. Upload new file > rename > save > delete old file (using old name).